# How to run external process in Scala and get both exit code and output?

Tags: scala, process, external

How to call an external process and read both of its exit code and standard out, once it finished?

Using `sys.Process` will result in an exception being thrown on different exit code than 0 for success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys.process._

val stdout = new StringBuilder
val stderr = new StringBuilder
val logger = ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _)
val status = "ls -al " ! logger

println(status)
println("stdout: " + stdout)
println("stderr: " + stderr)
```

Then you got both of them: status, stdout and stderr.

Comment: Thank you; simpler and more Scalaesque than the accepted solution, and worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Process.exitValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29)?

> Returns the exit value for the subprocess.

Comment: yes, however, bare Process throws on supposed exitValue being other than 0, I'm not sure whether I can get both output and exit code with it? (I've changed my approach to ProcessBuilder, which solved the issue using the function you suggested)

Answer (score 1):

(I've asked this question on freenode #java and was requested to post here if I found a solution, so here goes)

Simple approach is to use sys.ProcessBuilder:

```
  def RunExternal(executableName: String, executableDir: String) : (Int, List[String]) = {
    val startExecutionTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val pb : ProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder (executableName)
    pb.directory(new java.io.File(executableDir))

    val proc = pb.start()
    proc.waitFor()

    val exitCode = proc.exitValue()
    val output = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(proc.getInputStream).getLines.toList

    val executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startExecutionTime

    logger.info(String.format(s"Process exited with exit code: ${exitCode}."))
    logger.info(String.format(s"Process took ${executionTime} milliseconds."))

    (exitCode, output)
  }
```

Comment: error: trait ProcessBuilder is abstract; cannot be instantiated